# Chart js mostrar información dentro del diagrama

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Tomando como base el siguiente diagrama hecho en Char.js [Diagrama de pastel](http://jsfiddle.net/JSDesign/wprnvyd1/)

```js
// global options variable
var options = {
  responsive: true,
  scaleBeginAtZero: true,
  // you don't have to define this here, it exists inside the global defaults
  legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
}

// PIE
// PROPERTY TYPE DISTRIBUTION
// context
var ctxPTD = $("#property_types").get(0).getContext("2d");
// data
var dataPTD = [{
    label: "Single Family Residence",
    color: "#5093ce",
    highlight: "#78acd9",
    value: 52
  },
  {
    label: "Townhouse/Condo",
    color: "#c7ccd1",
    highlight: "#e3e6e8",
    value: 12
  }

]

// Property Type Distribution
var propertyTypes = new Chart(ctxPTD).Pie(dataPTD, options);
// pie chart legend
$("#pie_legend").html(propertyTypes.generateLegend());
```

```css
.pie-legend {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.pie-legend span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-right: 16px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}

.pie-legend li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart">
  <canvas id="property_types" class="pie"></canvas>
  <div id="pie_legend"></div>
</div>
```

Cómo puedo ajustar el código para que solo se pueda visualizar en el centro del diagrama el Porcentaje completado.

Por ejemplo: mostrar solo el `52%` de Single Family Residence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me he basado [en esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30504672/3045491) para crear un valor central.

En `options` agregas un `onAnimationProgress` para que se ejecute una función.

Ahi modifico el `css` para que lo ponga en medio, buscando en los datos de `dataPTD` aquel que tenga el color azul.

```js
// global options variable
var options = {
  responsive: true,
  scaleBeginAtZero: true,
  // you don't have to define this here, it exists inside the global defaults
  legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>",

onAnimationProgress: valorCentral
  
}
Chart.defaults.global.showTooltips = false;

// PIE
// PROPERTY TYPE DISTRIBUTION
// context
var ctxPTD = $("#property_types").get(0).getContext("2d");
// data
var dataPTD = [{
    label: "Single Family Residence",
    color: "#5093ce",
    highlight: "#78acd9",
    value: 52
  },
  {
    label: "Townhouse/Condo",
    color: "#c7ccd1",
    highlight: "#e3e6e8",
    value: 12
  },
  {
    label: "Land",
    color: "#7fc77f",
    highlight: "#a3d7a3",
    value: 6
  },
  {
    label: "Multifamily",
    color: "#fab657",
    highlight: "#fbcb88",
    value: 8
  },
  {
    label: "Farm/Ranch",
    color: "#eaaede",
    highlight: "#f5d6ef",
    value: 8
  },
  {
    label: "Commercial",
    color: "#dd6864",
    highlight: "#e6918e",
    value: 14
  },

]

// Property Type Distribution
var propertyTypes = new Chart(ctxPTD).Pie(dataPTD, options);
// pie chart legend
$("#pie_legend").html(propertyTypes.generateLegend());

function valorCentral(){

  var tooltipEl = $('#chartjs-tooltip');

  tooltipEl.removeClass('above below');
  tooltipEl.addClass(tooltipEl.yAlign);


  var innerHtml = '<b>' + colorAzulValue() + '%</b></span>';
  tooltipEl.html(innerHtml);
  var canvas = document.getElementById("property_types");
  tooltipEl.css({
    opacity: 1,
    left: canvas.width / 2 + 'px',
    top: canvas.height / 2 + 'px',
    fontFamily: tooltipEl.fontFamily,
    fontSize: tooltipEl.fontSize,
    fontStyle: tooltipEl.fontStyle,
  });
}

function colorAzulValue() {

  for (var i = 0; i < dataPTD.length; i++) {
    
    var colorSegmento = dataPTD[i].color;
    //alert (colorSegmento);
    if(colorSegmento === "#5093ce" ) return dataPTD[i].value;
    
  }

}
```

```css
.pie-legend {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
 

.pie-legend span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-right: 16px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}

.pie-legend li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#chartjs-tooltip {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  color: white;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart">
  <canvas id="property_types" class="pie"></canvas>
  <div id="pie_legend"></div>
</div>
<div id="chartjs-tooltip"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, eso es exactamente lo que buscaba, muchas gracias lois6b me has ayudado mucho... Ajustaré algunas cosas, pero en verdad muchas gracias he